# unable to access the link of pdf in iphone

Tags: iphone, pdf, ios4, hyperlink, pdf-viewer

I am working on the application, in which I need to access the links which are in the pdf. Text which are in linked shows in different color but there is no click option in iphone to visit that links. same pdf shows link in browser and can be accessible.
Does anybody has any idea how this could be possible.
Thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the webview to show the PDF and then in the webview make sure that the detectlink property is changed to true,this might solve your query